# Can I call stored procedure in Data model before other queries in Oracle BI Publisher?

Tags: sql, oracle, business-intelligence, bi-publisher, oracle-bi

I have 2 SQL queries that I need to call in data model, but before calling them I need to execute stored procedure with parameters.

Is this possible in BI Publisher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible using Event Triggers. This feature is available from version 11.1.1.6. You can refer documentation here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/e22258/add_event_trig.htm#BIPDM331

**Update:**
As per documentation only functions are allowed. 
"The BI Publisher data model supports before data and after data triggers that execute a PL/SQL function stored in a PL/SQL package in your Oracle Database. The return data type for a PL/SQL function inside the package must be a Boolean type and the function must explicitly return TRUE or FALSE."

Comment: It should be only function? Because I can't see my stored procedures there.

Comment: Yes you are right, only functions are possible; as per documentation "The BI Publisher data model supports before data and after data triggers that execute a PL/SQL function stored in a PL/SQL package in your Oracle Database. The return data type for a PL/SQL function inside the package must be a Boolean type and the function must explicitly return TRUE or FALSE."